# Check if a given string can be a palindrome by altering some character without using a library function

Tags: java, interview-questions, palindrome

I was asked in an interview to write code to check if a given string is a palindrome or can be a palindrome by altering some character without using library function.

My logic is to:

- Compare 1st `char` with remaining `char`s. If it exists, remove both from array using `removeElement()`.
- If it does not exist in the `char` array, then use `removeFirstElement()` to remove the first element 1 time only.
- `chackPotentialPalindrom()` returns `true` if a `String` can be a palindrome, otherwise `false`.

```
package package1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrom {
    static int  temp=0;
    static char[] cArr;
        static boolean chackPotentialPalindrom(char[] cAr){
            cArr=cAr;
            if(cArr!=null){
                char current=cArr[0];
                for(int i=1;i<cArr.length;i++){
                    if(current==cArr[i]){
                        cArr=removeElement(i);
                        chackPotentialPalindrom(cArr);
                        break;
                    } 
                    }
                if(cAr.length==2){
                if(cAr[0]==cAr[1]){
                    cArr=null;
                }}
                if(temp==0 && cArr!=null){
                    temp=1;
                    cArr=removeFirstElement(cArr);
                    chackPotentialPalindrom(cArr);
                    }
                }
            if(cArr==null){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        static char[] removeFirstElement(char[] cAr){
            cArr=cAr;
            if(cArr!=null){
            if(cArr.length >1){
            char[] cArrnew=new char[cArr.length-1];
            for(int j=1,k=0;j<cArr.length;j++,k++){
                cArrnew[k]=cArr[j];
            }
            return cArrnew;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
        }
        static char[] removeElement(int i){
            if(cArr.length>2){
            char[] cArrnew=new char[cArr.length-2];
            for(int j=1,k=0;j<cArr.length;j++,k++){
                if(i!=j){
                    cArrnew[k]=cArr[j];
                }else{
                    k-=1;
                }
            }
            return cArrnew;}
            else{
                return null;
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
            while(true){
                temp=0;
            String s=scn.next();
            char[] arr=s.toCharArray();
            System.out.println(chackPotentialPalindrom(arr));
            }
        }
    }
```

- Any tips to optimize this code?
- I could not write this in an interview as they have given a pen and paper to code.
- It took 3 hrs for me to write this. Can I be a developer?

Comment: It would be nice if you could also show example inputs and outputs to illustrate the 'alter some character'... I'm assuming it's to alter a *single* character...?

Comment: Sure, you can become a developer, but writing code like this on pen and paper should not be that difficult. In this case, for me, the assignment itself is pretty vague and should be more clear. Just give yourself time to gain more experience. small hint: this -> 
if(cArr==null){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

can be written as:

return cArr==null;

Comment: you definitely can be developer

Comment: And while writing code with pen and paper in interview, don't get worried about syntax, if your logic is correct you will get selected.

Comment: Ya input- abcab ,aabbc  will give O/P- true
 
abcab is not a palindrome but abcba is by altering last two char
aabbc can be a palindrome like abcba or bacab

Comment: Overcomplicated. All you need is to count occurrence of every character in input string. If length of input string is even, string can be a palindrome if every character occurs even times. If length of input string is odd, there should be one character that occurs odd times.

Comment: for the `aabbc` example: isn't that extremely liberal and ambiguous then, for a palindrome checker? I can still understand *switching* the placements of two neighboring characters, but to convert `aabbc` to `abcba` is quite a stretch... I can have potentially garbage inputs like 1000x `a` followed by `c`, and still expect the method to return `true` by treating it as a middle `c` with 500x `a` on each side?

Comment: By altering I meant changing the character index to any position 
not swapping  with any other char

Comment: Looking at the  `chackPotentialPalindrom` the first loop looks a bit dodgy. You are running from 1 to the length of cArr but are changing the contents of cArr in the body of the loop. AFAIK, the length is grabbed once at the top of the loop and not re-evaluated. At little test program seems to confirm this but my java is only so-so. Can anyone confirm/refute this? It seems like it should cause an index error

Comment: Anyone can be a developer with hard work and practice.

Answer (score 2):

The above looks to be more work than is necessary. Assuming that we are working with all lower case chars, the following should work.

We match the chars at each end, moving inwards on each cycle. Normally, if any do not match, we consider it a fail and break out. If we are allowed a one pair mismatch (i.e. change one character), then we need to keep track of the count of mismatches and if we have 0 or 1 (less than 2) we consider it to be a palindrome.

```
private static boolean isAlmostPalindrome(String str){
    int diffCount = 0;
    int left = 0;
    int right = str.length() -1;

    while(right>left){
        if (str.charAt(right--)!= str.charAt(left++)){
            diffCount++;
        }
    }
    return diffCount <2;
}
```

Comment: Until we get a better clarification from OP about this 'alternation' rule, I still think this suggestion is potentially flawed: `abcbe` will `return true` for your method, but the desired output may be `false` if we *assume* that the character `e` can't be 'altered' with any other characters *within* the input... that's the clarification we need. :)

Comment: @h.j.k. `abcde` was one of the test cases that I used and it returns false.  a/e, b/d both mis-match thus we have a count of 2 and a false result. Some clarification on the reqs is always good :) but I would interpret 'altering a character' as changing the value for it whereas swapping two characters would count as altering two characters.

Comment: I typed abc**b**e ;)

Comment: @h.j.k. my bad!  We are back to the reqs. If altering means change the value, then `true` is correct. change the e to an a. If altering means swap with another then it should be `false` as no arrangement of **abbce** can ever be a palindrome.

Comment: Question is not only to check for palindrome.

Answer (score 2):

Why not count all occurrences of the letters? Also count the string length.

1. If the string length is even and all characters occur even number of times, then it is a palindrome.
2. If the string length is odd and all characters occur even number of times except for one character that occurs odd number of times, then it is a palindrome.
3. Otherwise, it is not.

Comment: This is not an accurate way of finding a palindrome.  According to your method, "aabb" is a palindrome, and so is "aabbc".

Comment: @Hosch250 look at clarifying comments on question. It is allowed to change order of characters, so the answer is correct.

Comment: @ŁukaszCiosek OK, thanks for the comment.

Comment: This approach will work fine but I think it will take same effort as mine  ,as we are we have to write without  using library function.

Answer (score 1):

For every character in the string, check if the occurrence of that character in the string is an even number. Repeat this for every character and we can tolerate a maximum of 1 odd number. It's funny how people tend to over-think simple situation like this.

Comment: "can be a palindrome by altering some characters". Read the details, that's what make you a good programmer :)
Edit: AACCB can be altered to become a palindrome : ACBCA

Comment: I think years of being confronted with adverts, bylines and people-who-shout-all-the-time mean I now never read anything in bold or upper case!  I retract my complaint! Sorry.

Comment: yeah, just throught we were looking for comparison, I'm only up at this insane time because I'm really congested, probably time to go back to bed....

Answer (score 1):

The logic here is to find a character and its number of occurrence then check if that has more than one odd number of characters exist. If so, then the string cannot be a palindrome, else it will be a palindrome. I checked with few complex inputs and it worked fine. If the method returns "YES" then it could be altered and can be palindrome, if not, then "NO".

```
 static String got(String password) {
    HashMap<Character, Integer> checkpass = new HashMap<>();
    Character ch = null;
    Integer val = 0;
    int odd = 0, even = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
        ch = password.charAt(i);
        if (checkpass.containsKey(ch) == false) {
            checkpass.put(ch, 1);
        } else {
            val = (Integer) checkpass.get(ch);
            checkpass.put(ch, val + 1);
        }
    }
    Set<Character> hashval = checkpass.keySet();
    for (Character key : hashval) {
        val = (Integer) checkpass.get(key);
        if (val == password.length())
            return "YES";
        else if (val % 2 == 1)
            odd++;
        else
            even++;
    }
    if (odd == 1 || odd == 0)
        return "YES";
    else
        return "NO";
}
```

Comment: This code will work perfectly fine but you are using library function in this.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is old, but I happened to look at this today.  And there are assertions in comments with which I disagree.

It is possible to write this more briefly and simply.  As described at [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/88383/71574).  Note:  I dropped the even/odd distinction overall, as it is unnecessary.  The only way to get exactly one odd letter count is for the overall string to be odd length.  So we can combine both checks into whether or not there is more than one character with an odd count.

```
public static boolean canBePalindrome(char[] characters) {
    if (characters == null) {
        return true;
    }

    int[] counts = new int[65536];
    for (char c : characters) {
        counts[(int)c]++;
    }

    boolean oddSeen = false;
    for (int count : counts) {
        if (count % 2 != 0) {
            if (oddSeen) {
                return false;
            }

            oddSeen = true;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Java characters are sixteen bit integers.  So we can cover all of them with 65536 values.  You may be able to check fewer.  For example, the question may cover only standard ASCII characters or even just Latin letters.  It is not necessary to use a `Map` as [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/88884/71574) did, although it may be faster.

This may not handle extended Unicode correctly, but neither did the original code.  So I have at least not introduced new bugs by handling each character singly (extended Unicode may require two characters to display one character).

We can, with one iteration through the characters, count all of them.

Then, with one iteration through the alphabet, we can check to see if two or more characters have odd counts.  If true, that tells us that it can't be reordered into a palindrome and we can return false.  If we get through the entire array without finding more than one odd count, then it can be ordered as a palindrome and we return true.

This is much simpler than the original code.  Just two range-based `for` loops and three `if` statements.  Two loop variables and two auxiliary variables, all primitives.  No library routines nor objects.  And no recursive calls nor even helper methods.

This code is linear in the input size from the first `for` loop.  The second loop runs within constant time (or at least the time is not affected by the size of the input; we could make it more consistent by turning `oddSeen` into a count rather than a `boolean`).  Your code is at least quadratic, as you essentially look through the entire array for a match and you have to check for matches to half the characters.

Answer (score -1):

It's late and I'm not really awake, but should be able to do it by processing array elements together.  For odd length strings, the middle element is obviously equals and I believe this skips it.

```
boolean success = true;
char[] array = stringToCheck.toCharArray();
int length = stringToCheck.length();
int halfLength = (int) length / 2;

for (int i = 0; sucess && i < halfLength; i++) {
   success = (array[i] == array[length - 1 - i]);
}

System.out.println ("Palindrome=" + success);
```

So much simpler than you were making it out to be.

Comment: Here the question is not only checking whether the string is palindrome, but also to check whether any alteration made to strings (swaps) could make it palindrome.  Eg, acdfcda, swapping 5,6 characters make this palindrome and should return true, if I am not wrong